# How to remove the old cart product after customer login

Tags: magento-enterprise, cart, customer-account

Customer visit website and add the product,

then customer login.

if customer already have cart items, its removed old items, newly added items only showing

**Example:**

Customer already have 5 products in cart > Visit the site > add newly 2 products in cart > login customer account > show the cart newly add 2 product (old cart products are removed)

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this event **sales_quote_merge_before**

put  this in config.xml

```
<events> 
   <sales_quote_merge_before><!--calling this event before merging the old cart with newly added cart items while login--> 
       <observers> 
            <ws_clearoldcartproducts_observer><!--unique identifier name for our observer--> 
                <type>singleton</type> 
                <class>Ws_Clearoldcartproducts_Model_Observer</class><!--Our observer class name--> 
                <method>loadCustomerQuote</method><!--Method to be called from our observer class--> 
            </ws_clearoldcartproducts_observer> 
        </observers> 
    </sales_quote_merge_before> 
</events>
```

put this in observer.php

```
public function loadCustomerQuote() 
{ 
    $customerQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote') 
                        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                        ->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId()
                    ); 
    if ($customerQuote->getId() && $this->getQuoteId() != $customerQuote->getId()) 
    { 
        // Removing old cart items of the customer. 
        foreach ($customerQuote->getAllItems() as $item) 
        { 
            $item->isDeleted(true); 
            if ($item->getHasChildren()) { 
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) { 
                    $child->isDeleted(true); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        $customerQuote->collectTotals()->save(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress(); 
        $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress(); 
        $this->getQuote()->setCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()) ->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false) ->collectTotals() ->save();
    } 
    return $this; 
}
```

Refer this [**link**](http://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-avoid-merging-old-cart-items-in-magento/)

Comment: i got the answer from the link. thanks @surya

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you hook onto the event called `sales_quote_merge_before` and empty one of the cart (the existing one for example).
This event is triggered after login and before `sales_quote_collect_totals_before`

Comment: were you able to achieve what you wanted this way? or does it not quite intervene where you'd like it to.