# Make cart empty after login

Tags: cart, customer-account

I am in situation where I have to remove all products from cart after user logs in.

I have seen code examples to remove previous cart items, but don't know how to make the cart completely empty after the user logs in.
[How to remove the old cart product after customer login](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/how-to-remove-the-old-cart-product-after-customer-login)

The above url is for the logic
Customer already have 5 products in cart > Visit the site > add newly 2 products in cart > login customer account > show the cart newly add 2 product (old cart products are removed)

But in my case, When the customer logs in all 7 products has to be removed from cart.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this help you? http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/clear-abandoned-cart-items-during-login-in-magento/

Answer (score 2):

Use an event observer to empty cart on customer login.

config.xml

```
<customer_login>
  <observers>
      <foo_bar> <!-- foo_bar should be unique tag for within all customer_login observers-->
          <class>foo_bar/observer</class>
          <method>customerLogin</method>
          <type>singleton</type>
      </foo_bar>
  </observers>
</customer_login>
```

Observer

```
class Foo_Bar_Model_Observer {
    public function customerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can directly call `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate()->save();` in the observer.