# In Magento 1.9.3.3 how to make empty cart whenever customer logged in?

Tags: cart

If you have any idea then please share here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Mage_Customer_Model_Session model's method setCustomerAsLoggedIn() an event customer_login is being dispatched. I guess you need to hook in on that event. You could do this as follows.

Add the event to your module's config.xml file (app/code/local/Lpf/ModuleCookie/etc/config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Lpf_ModuleCookie>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </Lpf_ModuleCookie>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <lpf_modulecookie>
            <class>Lpf_ModuleCookie_Model</class>
        </lpf_modulecookie>
    </models>
</global>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <lpf_modulecookie_customer_login>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>lpf_modulecookie/observer</class>
                    <method>customerLogin</method>
                </lpf_modulecookie_customer_login>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Now create a model Lpf_ModuleCookie_Model_Observer (app/code/local/Lpf/ModuleCookie/Model/Observer.php). Add a customerLogin() method to the class:

```
 <?php
 class Lpf_ModuleCookie_Model_Observer
 {

 /**
  * Run couple of 'php' codes after customer logs in
  *
  * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
  */
 public function customerLogin($observer)
 {
     $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) 
    {
        $item->isDeleted(true);
        if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
            foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                $child->isDeleted(true);
            }
        }
    }
    $quote->collectTotals()->save(); 
 }
 }
```

Reference : [How to bind an action after customer login success using Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/how-to-bind-an-action-after-customer-login-success-using-magento)

Comment: We do that but not working.

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: Sorry, this one also not working.

Comment: did you clear all cache in magento admin and test it?

Comment: if we print anything before Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate(); then displayed but not delete cart items.

Comment: yes clear all Magento cache then after we checked

Comment: @Ashish , Please check updated answer.

Comment: Still not working @chirag Rajput

Comment: `$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
     foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) 
     {
            $item->isDeleted(true);
            if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    $child->isDeleted(true);
                }
            }
        }
        $quote->collectTotals()->save(); ` this is works for us.

Comment: Are you using any extra cache?

Comment: already done with other code. thanks for support @chirag

Comment: Cool :) @AshishKacha

Comment: @AshishKacha , you can share your code, and make it correct mark . so in future it help someone.

Comment: `public function loadCustomerQuote() 
    {
     $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
     foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) 
     {
            $item->isDeleted(true);
            if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    $child->isDeleted(true);
                }
            }
        }
        $quote->collectTotals()->save(); 
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this event **sales_quote_merge_before**

Put this in `config.xml` In below-mentioned code, we are using `sales_quote_merge_before` observer to clear old items.

```
<events> 
   <sales_quote_merge_before><!--calling this event before merging the old cart with newly added cart items while login--> 
       <observers> 
            <ws_clearoldcartproducts_observer><!--unique identifier name for our observer--> 
                <type>singleton</type> 
                <class>Ws_Clearoldcartproducts_Model_Observer</class><!--Our observer class name--> 
                <method>loadCustomerQuote</method><!--Method to be called from our observer class--> 
            </ws_clearoldcartproducts_observer> 
        </observers> 
    </sales_quote_merge_before> 
</events>
```

Put this in `observer.php`

```
public function loadCustomerQuote() 
{ 
    $customerQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote') 
                        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                        ->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId()
                    ); 
    if ($customerQuote->getId() && $this->getQuoteId() != $customerQuote->getId()) 
    { 
        // Removing old cart items of the customer. 
        foreach ($customerQuote->getAllItems() as $item) 
        { 
            $item->isDeleted(true); 
            if ($item->getHasChildren()) { 
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) { 
                    $child->isDeleted(true); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        $customerQuote->collectTotals()->save(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress(); 
        $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress(); 
        $this->getQuote()->setCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()) ->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false) ->collectTotals() ->save();
    } 
    return $this; 
}
```

We have find this solution from this [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19868/17154). Thanks to [Surya](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/6428/surya) for this solution.

Hope that'll help you.

Comment: @AshishKacha try this solution maybe that'll help you.

Comment: @Ashish-Kacha Please let me know is that working for you or not.?

Comment: If you copy another ones answer, please leave some credits :)

Comment: Not working for us. @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.